# find the value of $dy/dx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose a solution of the differential equation
$(xy^3 +x^2y^7)dy/dx = 1$
satisfies the initial condition
$y(1/4)= 1$.  Then find the value of $dy/dx$ when $y=-1$.

my approach:

1) doing integration

2) finding the value of integration constant by putting $x=1/4$, $y=1$

3) putting $y=-1$  and value of integration constant to find out $x$

4) putting $x$ and $y$ in the first equation to find $dy/dx$.

The problem is I'm not getting the correct value of $dy/dx$.

options are a) $4/3$ b) $-4/3$ c) $16/5$ d)$-16/5$

Comment: This is neither separable nor homogeneous and any integrating factor must be a function of both $x$ and $y$. Have you found an integrating factor?

Answer (score 3):

My solution: first rewrite with y as the independent variable:
$$\frac{dx}{dy}-y^3x=y^7x^2$$
This is Bernoulli's differential equation, so we let $x=u^n$ and when $n-1=2n$ the dependent variable will be removed from the right hand side. Thus $n=-1$ so $x=\frac1u$,
$$-\frac1{u^2}\frac{du}{dy}-y^3u^{-1}=y^7u^{-2}$$
$$\frac{du}{dy}+y^3u=-y^7$$
This is first order linear but the integrating factor is unpleasant, so we try $y=v^m$. Then $\frac{dy}{dv}=mv^{m-1}$ and so
$$\frac{du}{dy}+y^3u=\frac{du}{dv}\frac{dv}{dy}+v^{3m}u=\frac{du}{dv}\frac{dv}{dy}+v^{3m}u=\frac1{mv^{m-1}}\frac{du}{dv}+v^{3m}u=-v^{7m}$$
Rearrange to
$$\frac{du}{dv}+mv^{4m-1}u=-mv^{8m-1}$$
And it looks like $m=\frac14$ would be a good choice. Then $y=v^{\frac14}$ and
$$\frac{du}{dv}+\frac14u=-\frac14v$$
Now the integrating factor is $\mu=e^{\int\frac14dv}=e^{\frac14v}$ is no problem and
$$\frac d{dv}\left(e^{\frac14v}u\right)=e^{\frac14v}\frac{du}{dv}+\frac14e^{\frac14v}u=-\frac14ve^{\frac14v}$$
We can do this integral with tabular integration to get
$$e^{\frac14v}u=(-v+4)e^{\frac14v}+C$$
Back into the original variables,
$$\frac1xe^{\frac14y^4}=(-y^4+4)e^{\frac14y^4}+C$$
Applying initial conditions,
$$4e^{\frac14}=3e^{\frac14}+C$$
So $C=e^{\frac14}$. Then when $y=-1$,
$$\frac1xe^{\frac14}=(-1+4)e^{\frac14}+e^{\frac14}$$
Thus $x=\frac14$, and substituting into the original differential equation,
$$\left(\frac14(-1)+\frac1{16}(-1)\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
And so we arrive at $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{16}5$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(xy^3+x^2y^7)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=1$$
For $x=1/4$ and $y=1$ we obtain : $(\frac{1}{4}(1)^3 +\frac{1}{4^2}(1)^7)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = 1 \quad\to\quad \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{y=1}=\frac{16}{5}$

We observe that changing $y$ into $-y$ doesn't change the ODE.

Thus, the function $x(y)$ is even.

As a consequence $\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)_{y=-1}=-\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)_{y=1} \qquad\to\qquad \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{y=-1}=-\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{y=1}$

$$\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)_{y=-1}=-\frac{16}{5}$$